# Web service return type for populating a php combobox

Tags: php, asp.net

In our company, we have an asp.net project, and a php project, that would consume a web service to populate a combobox.

My question is, can i return a Ador.Recordset, or do i have to create a xml?

And if i want to send data from php to asp.net, would i have to create another xml?

Answer (score 0):

I create an asmx file in ASP.net, and return a List < HashTable >

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public List<Hashtable> MyService()
{
    List<Hashtable> ht = new List<Hashtable>();
    DataTable = new DataTable();
    // Fill my data table here then convert it to a hash table list
    ht = strings.ConvertDataTableToHashTable(dt);
    dt.Dispose();
    return ht;
}
```

This will automatically return a JSON object which you can use with JQuery/JavaScript within your PHP

Answer (score 0):

PHP will not understand Ador.Recordset because it is asp.net specific object.

The best medium to communicate between various systems, do not understand each other is XML, like many middle wears using now-a-days.

Alternatively you can put in database by php and read by asp.net, or put in a file, or create CSV with php and parse with asp.net but XML is the best approach.